# How come {}"123" is a valid expression in Javascript REPL?

Tags: javascript

I was trying something in the Chrome (and FF) console and realized that the JS REPL evaluates some expressions in a surprising way:

```
{} "123" 
-> "123"


{} 123 
-> 123

{} [] 
-> []
```

Etc.

Why is that? Also, somewhat inconsistent with the previous behavior:

```
{}{} 
-> undefined
```

What's the logic behind the fact that these are valid expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Semicolons are optional in Javascript. So:

`{} "123"` is the same as `{}; "123";` which yield the value of the last expression (`"123"`).

2. `{}` could be both an object literal or a block.

If `{}` is not implicitly taken as an object literal (no assignment or no key value pairs ...) then the interpreter will parse it as a block.

`{}{}` is the same as:

```
{
  // block with no expressions
};
{
  // block with no expressions
};
```

yielding `undefined` which is the value of an empty block.